# Box2D check for a POTENTIAL collision

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision-detection, detection

I want to check in box2D, if I placed a body right there, would it be in another body, and if not, I don't wanna place/move a body right there.

I am using LIBGDX

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is your code sample?

Comment: Well I searched for some methods and I also googled, but I didn't find anything good. I don't know if it is a good idea to add a body to remove it a second after, but this could work. I just wanted to know if anyone knows how to do this properly

Answer (score 1):

Try Box2D raycasting:

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/raycasting

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/world-querying

*/I should place it as a comment but I cant :/*